# How to detect undefined in ngSwitch and ngSwitchWhen? (Angular 2)

Tags: typescript, angular

How to detect **undefined** in `ngSwitch` and `ngSwitchWhen`?

I tried these three ways below, but neither works. It always shows **Not undefined**.

Thanks

```
<div [ngSwitch]="value">
  <p *ngSwitchWhen="undefined">11</p>
  <p *ngSwitchWhen="'undefined'">22</p>
  <p *ngSwitchWhen="">33</p>
  <p *ngSwitchDefault>Not undefined</p>
</div>

value: string;
```

**UPDATE:**

@basarat pointed out why it is like this, and please follow this for more details:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7637#issuecomment-197619354

Comment: You don't use `*` for structural directives when they are on a template tag. `*` is for the short form where you can omit the template tag

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thanks, give some time to test again.

Comment: I see, you also changed the template tag to `<p>` then its fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `ngSwitchWhen` uses angular's `===` check which is broken as shown in the following example:

```
import {
  bootstrap, 
  Component, 
  View,
  NgSwitch,
  NgSwitchWhen,
  NgSwitchDefault
} from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
})
@View({
  template: `
    <p>Value = {{value === undefined}}</p>
    <p>Value = {{value == undefined}}</p>

    <div [ng-switch]="value">
      <p *ng-switch-when="undefined">UNDEFINED</p>
      <p *ng-switch-default>DEF</p>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: [NgSwitch, NgSwitchWhen, NgSwitchDefault]
})
export class App {
  value = undefined;
}

bootstrap(App)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

`=== undefined` comes out as false but `== undefined` comes out as true.

Here is the plunkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/DQMTII95CbuqWrl3lYAs?p=preview

## More

Suggest you report it here : https://github.com/angular/angular/issues

Comment: your plunkr link is original demo. [This plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/2RQHJcX01vFx1uUgzTzd?p=preview) did the test based on yours and use latest angular2 version. I will report it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is an open issue to support `undefined` in the template https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7625

---

**This doesn't work as of RC.2**

Not tested but I assume this does what you want

```
 <template [ngSwitchCase]="undefined">22</template>

 <!-- <= RC.1 versions -->
 <template [ngSwitchWhen]="undefined">22</template>
```

Your first two `ngSwitch` test for the string undefined.

Comment: thanks, only change `*ngSwitchWhen` to `[ngSwitchWhen]`, right? Unfortunately, it does not work

Comment: What does "does not work" mean? Do you get an error message?

Comment: so right now if I change from `<p *ngSwitchWhen="'undefined'">22</p>` to `<p [ngSwitchWhen]="'undefined'">22</p>`, it shows: `EXCEPTION: No provider for TemplateRef! (NgSwitchWhen -> TemplateRef)`

Comment: I'm only on my phone and can't test myself before tomorrow or the day after.

Answer (score 0):

use ngSwitchCase instead of ngSwitchWhen.
then it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use ngIf instead

```
*ngIf="value === undefined"
```